# Create subset by week pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this:

```
x      |     week
___________________
234    |     40
345    |     40             
123    |     41   
155    |     41
213    |     41       
...    |     ...             
1452   |     52
```

and I need to create several data frames that each contains only one week

one for week 40, one for week 41, etc.

I have tried this so far:

```
length = len(data.index)-1
firstweek=data['week'].iloc[0]
lastweek=data['week'].iloc[length]
df = {}
for i in range (firstweek,lastweek):
     df[i]= pd.DataFrame(data.query('week== i'))
```

Comment: what is the issue exactly...does the code not work?

Comment: it sends me an error that i is not defined in the line of "df[i]=pd.DataFrame(data.query(´week==i´))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hard coded the variable `i`.  Assuming you're using Python 3.6+, you can use an f string for string interpolation.  If you're using Python 2 or an earlier version of 3, you can use the .format method.

**Python 3.6 +**

```
length = len(data.index)-1
firstweek=data['week'].iloc[0]
lastweek=data['week'].iloc[length]
df = {}
for i in range (firstweek,lastweek):
     df[i]= pd.DataFrame(data.query(f'week=={i}'))
```

**Python 2 & 3**

```
length = len(data.index)-1
firstweek=data['week'].iloc[0]
lastweek=data['week'].iloc[length]
df = {}
for i in range (firstweek,lastweek):
     df[i]= pd.DataFrame(data.query('week=={i}'.format(i=i)))
```

Further reading: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation